# @font-face Font not loading into mpdf

Tags: fonts, yii2, mpdf

I'm loading in the Google Railway-Light font for my website, and it works fine, but it doesn't load into the PDF I'm generating. I'm calling it in my CSS file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Raleway-Light";
    src: url("../font/Raleway-Light.ttf");
}
```

And I'm calling in the CSS file when I generate the PDF.

```
$pdf = new Pdf(
    [
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_LETTER,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        'content' => $content,
        'cssFile' => '/var/www/html/basic/web/css/sites.css',
        'marginRight' => 0,
        'marginLeft' => 0,
        'marginTop' => 0,
        'marginBottom' => 0,
        'marginHeader' => 0,
        'marginFooter' => 0,

        'cssInline' => '',
        'options' => [],
        'methods' => [],
    ]
);

if ($user->role == 0) {
    $pdf->showWaterMark = true;
}
// return the pdf output as per the destination setting
return $pdf->render();
```

I loaded that font into the `mpdf/ttf` folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
```

needed to be set to

```
'mode' => '',
```

and then my font needed to be included in `FontVariables.php`